# pairwise operation on columns in R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe like this

```
sample <- data.frame(x1=c(1,2),y1=c(2,1), x2=c(2,4),y2=c(3,4),x3=c(5,2),y3=c(1,6))
```

How can I operate pairwise (sum up x1&y1, x2&y2, x3&y3, 2 columns at a time) to create 3 new columns sum1, sum2, sum3? Thanks

Comment: you want the rule for pairs (maybe larger groups too?) to be based on the numeral?

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1**

Since it is pairwise, you can do it with `mapply`.

Create two vectors referring to the pairs

```
p1 <- seq(1, 6, by = 2)
p2 <- seq(2, 6, by = 2)
```

Then use `mapply` to apply pairwise summation for the columns desired:

```
mapply(x = p1, y = p2, function(x, y) sample[[x]] + sample[[y]])
```

Result:

```
   [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    5    6
[2,]    3    8    8`
```

**Method 2**

I also like to use the packages `dplyr` and `wrapr` in conjunction if you need to output the pairwise operation in the sample table.

```
require(dplyr)
require(wrapr)

newcols <- paste0(names(sample)[seq(1, 6, by = 2)], names(sample)[seq(2, 6, by = 2)])

for (i in c(1:3)) {
  wrapr::let(list(RES = newcols[i],
                  COL1 = names(sample)[i],
                  COL2 = names(sample)[i + 1]),
             sample <- dplyr::mutate(sample, RES = COL1 + COL2))}


sample

  x1 y1 x2 y2 x3 y3 x1y1 x2y2 x3y3
1  1  2  2  3  5  1    3    4    5
2  2  1  4  4  2  6    3    5    8
```

I liek to use those packages because I find it easier to understand. But if you can't download those packages for any reason. You can do it with base R:

```
newcols <- paste0(names(sample)[seq(1, 6, by = 2)], names(sample)[seq(2, 6, by = 2)])

for (i in c(1:3)) {
             sample[newcols[i]] <- sample[, names(sample)[i]] + sample[, names(sample)[i + 1]]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
sample <- data.frame(x1=c(1,2),y1=c(2,1), 
x2=c(2,4),y2=c(3,4),x3=c(5,2),y3=c(1,6))
sample_new <- data.frame(x1=c(1,2),y1=c(2,1), 
x2=c(2,4),y2=c(3,4),x3=c(5,2),y3=c(1,6),sumx1y1=(sample$x1 + sample$y1), 
sumx2y2=(sample$x2 + sample$y2),sumx3y3=(sample$x3 + sample$y3))
```